# How can I verify users facebook ID that he provides during signup process

Tags: users, user-registration

In my signup form there is an input field that gets user's facebook ID, I just want to verify if its correct before signing up the user.

Comment: What do you mean by "correct"? You want to check if it exists or if it is used by given person (based on what: email address, name, ...?)?

Comment: I mean, I want to check if the provided facebook ID actually belongs to the person who is signing up

Comment: Based on e-mail address, name of this person, or what? I mean... I can sign up with my e-mail and provide facebook ID, but my FB profile can be assigned to different e-mail address.

Comment: It should be based on the active logged in Facebook ID.

facebook.com/<user-id> 
This user-id should match with the one he enters in my signup form field

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When user logs in using this FB button. Its session is generated. So I can use PHP API to get any information I want.

I put this code in html body

```
              <script>
  window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
  FB.init({
    appId      : <?php echo $facebook->getAppId(); ?>, // App ID
    channelUrl : '//WWW.example.com/channel.html', // Channel File
    status     : true, // check login status
    cookie     : true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
    xfbml      : true  // parse XFBML
  });

  // Here we subscribe to the auth.authResponseChange JavaScript event. This event is fired
  // for any authentication related change, such as login, logout or session refresh. This means that
  // whenever someone who was previously logged out tries to log in again, the correct case below 
  // will be handled. 
  FB.Event.subscribe('auth.authResponseChange', function(response) {
    // Here we specify what we do with the response anytime this event occurs. 
    if (response.status === 'connected') {
      // The response object is returned with a status field that lets the app know the current
      // login status of the person. In this case, we're handling the situation where they 
      // have logged in to the app.
      testAPI();
    } else if (response.status === 'not_authorized') {
      // In this case, the person is logged into Facebook, but not into the app, so we call
      // FB.login() to prompt them to do so. 
      // In real-life usage, you wouldn't want to immediately prompt someone to login 
      // like this, for two reasons:
      // (1) JavaScript created popup windows are blocked by most browsers unless they 
      // result from direct interaction from people using the app (such as a mouse click)
      // (2) it is a bad experience to be continually prompted to login upon page load.
      FB.login();
    } else {
      // In this case, the person is not logged into Facebook, so we call the login() 
      // function to prompt them to do so. Note that at this stage there is no indication
      // of whether they are logged into the app. If they aren't then they'll see the Login
      // dialog right after they log in to Facebook. 
      // The same caveats as above apply to the FB.login() call here.
      FB.login();
    }
  });
  };

  // Load the SDK asynchronously
  (function(d){
   var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk', ref = d.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
   if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
   js = d.createElement('script'); js.id = id; js.async = true;
   js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
   ref.parentNode.insertBefore(js, ref);
  }(document));

  // Here we run a very simple test of the Graph API after login is successful. 
  // This testAPI() function is only called in those cases. 
  function testAPI() {
    console.log('Welcome!  Fetching your information.... ');
    FB.api('/me', function(response) {
      console.log('Good to see you, ' + response.name + '.');
    });
  }
</script>
```

PHP Side Code

```
        $config = array();
        $config['appId'] = 'myappid';
        $config['secret'] = 'myappsecretid';
        $config['fileUpload'] = false; // optional

        $facebook = new Facebook($config);
        $access_token = FALSE;
        $user = $facebook->getUser();
        if($user){
          // The user is logged in
          try{
            $user_profile = $facebook->api('/me');
            $access_token = $facebook->getAccessToken();
            // Here : API call succeeded,
            // you have a valid access token
            print_r($user_profile);  // all the user info is in this object
          }
          catch(FacebookApiException $e){
            // Here : API call failed,
            // you don't have a valid access token
            // you have to send him to $facebook->getLoginUrl()
            $user = null;
          }
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this,

before signup test via ajax that is fb id exist and if reponse is +ve than process signup else show him message 'wrong fb id'.

ajax fx may be

```
<?php
function test(){
   if(isset($_POST['fb_id']) && $_POST['fb_id'] != ''):
      $test=wp_remote_get('http://graph.facebook.com/'.$_POST['fb_id']);
      $test=wp_remote_retrieve_body($test);
      $test=json_decode($test);
      //check any json element for valid id like username etc
      if(){//pass
        $status=array('status'=>'pass');
        echo json_encode($status);
      }else{//fail
        $error=array('status'=>'fail');
        echo json_encode($error);
      }
  else:
    $error=array('status'=>'fail');//in case empty value for fb id from form
    echo json_encode($error);
  endif;
die();
}
?>
```

Comment: looks like it will do what I want. I will try it and get back to you shortly. Thanks

Comment: actually, Facebook Javascript API login plugin did the trick.